# Why cannot implicitly implement a non-public interface member?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers, c#-8.0

**Interface:**

```
interface IMyInterface{
  internal int Property {get; set;}
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class MyClass: IMyInterface{
  internal int Property {get; set;}
}
```

**Result:**
CS8704 Error: MyClass doesnot implement interface member Property.get MyClass cannot implicitly implement a non-public member.

Why I have to implement the interface explicitly?

Comment: Interface members don't have scopes like public or internal. What you have here is a [default interface implementation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface members don't have scopes like public or internal. What you have here is a [default interface implementation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/).

So you need to remove the scope on the interface:

```
interface IMyInterface{
    int Property {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Interface members are implicitly public by default, but due to the changes in the default interface method project, they can now be declared internal, protected, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like internal property declaration in the interface: syntax is the same as for public property, but with the access modifier. Language designers could not allow auto-implemented properties at least. It would be much less confusing.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer to "why is a language like this" is "because that's how the language designers specified it".

Now, why did they design it that way? Some of the official notes I found were [these](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2017/LDM-2017-04-18.md#implicitly-implementing-non-public-interface-members). It seems the main question was about what kind of access the implementor must have:

> Would we allow non-public interface members to be implemented implicitly? If so, what is required of the accessibility of the implementing method? Some options:
>
> - Must be public
> - Must be the exact same accessibility
> - Must be at least as accessible

They decided:

> For now, let's simply not allow it. Only public interface members can be implicitly implemented (and only by public members).

The "for now" never changed, so as of C# 8 an interface can have non-public virtual members but a class may only implement them explicitly.

I can speculate on a couple of reasons they may have decided against implicit overrides like this:

- Non-public virtual methods in interfaces may have been considered a "rare" feature (after all, aren't interfaces supposed to document the public behavior of a class?), not worth putting a lot of resources into in terms of the semantics of implicit overrides.
- Unlike with method overridding in class-to-class inheritance, an class method implementing an interface method doesn't use the `override` keyword. It might have been considered confusing to see a protected and/or internal method and not realize that it's fulfilling an interface contract. (Public methods are presumably considered exempt from this concern because that's the way they've always worked, and public methods are part of the class' public contract anyway so modifying / removing them would already be cause the reader to think about other parts of code that depend on it.)
- Interfaces can only override other interface methods explicitly, possibly again because allowing interface-to-interface implicit implementation would be too expensive for the compiler and tooling teams and too confusing for C# users. (Especially since interface-to-interface inheritance is multiple-inheritance.) Since both this and non-public interface methods were introduced in general in C# 8, it may have made sense to make the two features match syntactically.

See also the [notes on this question in the default interface method proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#overriding-non-public-interface-members-closed).

Answer (score 1):

The internal property forces the implementation to be explicit such that the internal members of the interfaces will remain internal to the assembly.
It helps you to keep implementations internal (to an assembly) so that you can update code without breaking changes e.g. renaming the property.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    internal int Property { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    int IMyInterface.Property { get; set; }
}
```